# How can I add tablayout inside bottom navigation layout

Tags: java, android

I'm using Android Studio 3.5

I have found some old project on stack overflow that no longer works:

[Multiple Tab fragments inside bottom navigation fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561180/multiple-tab-fragments-inside-bottom-navigation-fragment)

[How to use tablayout with bottom navigation and viewpager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700551/how-to-use-tablayout-with-bottom-navigation-and-viewpager/51700655)

I really need this kind of layout, but I can't find any useful resources to help me build the project.

Please help me out this is my current state:
https://github.com/ericbig66/Tabbed-layou-inside-bottom-navigation

[image: This is the result I want to achieve]

Comment: warning, this repo is just to show the appearance, I really need help for the rest of the inner code

Answer (score 0):

What's the matter?!
When user clicks on bottom navigation, you open an fragment, and inside that fragment, you place a tab layout and view pager.

Comment: What I need is just put a functional tab layout inside a bottom navigation layout, I'm new to android studio, help me out

Comment: Those are two different things. I suggest you first learn how to use fragments. Second learn view pager, tab layout  & how to connect them. After these, learn how to implement bottom navigation.